# Discord OAuth2 login not working on Gitpod port

Tags: https, discord, discord.py, gitpod

I'm sorry for any lack of supporting code, I'm not sure what is needed to show for this question.

On my Django project I set up OAuth2 authentication for Discord and it has been working fine up until today, I'm not sure if it is because of the Discord data breach yesterday or not.

Now, when I try to authenticate via Discord through GitPod during development I get an https error saying the port is not secure and I can't log in. It seems my redirect isn't working anymore.

I'm not sure if there is some new setting or what needs to be done now, I really appreciate any help.

Comment: the breach has actually nothing to do with discord, discord.io was affected which is a service to share your servers.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could share any screenshots or example repository, or even how the final redirect URL looks like.

It could be that the redirect URL is not hitting your Gitpod workspace. You might get the issue resolved with port forwarding in place:

- https://www.gitpod.io/docs/configure/workspaces/ports#port-forwarding

I suspect that the redirect URL is pointing at `http://localhost:<some-port>` and not your Gitpod workspace magic port url (e.g. try running `gp url 3000`). Port forwarding can address that issue.